# JMeter: Is it possible to add HTTP Request sampler during run?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have an HTTP request that returns a JSON object that contains multiple urls (mostly image resources).
I do not know the number of the urls that will be in the response JSON and that number may vary during time.
I need to create an HTTP request for each of the urls that i received.

Is it possible to create HTTP Request samplers while running the JMeter flow?
Is there a different solution one can advise me to do in order to send HTTP requests to the list of the urls?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) as a child of the main request and come up with a [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression to extract links to images and whatever else URLs you would like to hit
2. Add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) and configure it to read the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference name from step 1 and set output variable to anything meaningful
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller and configure it to use the output variable
4. That's it, JMeter will trigger a HTTP Request sampler for each URL present in the original JSON

---

- Given you have the following JSON:

  ```
  {
    "urls": [
      {
        "url": "http://example.com"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://jmeter.apache.org"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://jmeter-plugins.org"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- You can extract the URLs into JMeter Variables using the following JSON Extractor setup:

  [image]

  it will give you the following JMeter Variables:

  ```
  url_1=http://example.com
  url_2=http://jmeter.apache.org
  url_3=http://jmeter-plugins.org
  url_matchNr=3
  ```

  [image]
- now if you add ForEach Controller and configure it like:

  [image]
- you will be able to refer the URLs as `${current_url}` in the HTTP Request sampler which is the child of the ForEach Controller

  [image]

Comment: The HTTP Request sampler inside the ForEach Controller is using the ${current_url}, but it also adds "http://" before the request. thus it fails
`GET http://[http://www.some url]/`

Comment: Put your `${current_url}` in "Path" section of the HTTP Request sampler